# send csv with polygon or line in gps data

Tags: carto, csv, import

I want to send a csv with a polygon or line to show it in cartoDB map but when I try to send data to the server I don´t know the exact way to send the info.
for polygon some think like this.
id,name,description,polygon
1,thename,a description, ((x,y),(x1,y1),(x2,y2))

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, do you have a solution for this issue?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq]

Answer (score 1):

You can put your polygons or lines in a geojson column. If necessary, you can transform that column in geometries using the `st_geomfromgeojson` function.

```
update yourcsv
set the_geom = st_geomfromgeojson(polygon1)
```

The question is more or less related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265412/cartodb-cannot-import-csv-with-geojson-column-working-with-cartodb

I don't know the format of your GPS data. Probably it is not difficult to convert it to GeoJSON.

I hope it helps.

Comment: The thin I want to do is import data into a new poligon table in cartodb server from my local database using a csv file but I don´t know the format to tell cartodb that the geo file is poligon and the current format to create the "csv" file.

Answer (score 1):

CartoDB will understand polygons like:

> POLYGON((10 10, 20 10, 20 20, 10 20, 10 10),
>   (13 13, 17 13, 17 17, 13 17, 13 13))

So you just need to add the "polygon" word before your coordinates for each one, and then, you'll be able to apply this:

> update table set the_geom = st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((10 10, 20 10, 20 20, 10 20, 10 10),
>   (13 13, 17 13, 17 17, 13 17, 13 13))'),4326)

If you have already an uploaded table whose column 'ColumnA' is the polygon text, you can just embed it in the SQL instead of using the text directly.